# Not first child - jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
    <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
    <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
    <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
    <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
</ul>
```

---

```
spec.find($(".sub-menu:not(:first-child)")).clone().prependTo("#sub-menu");
```

Im trying to move **.sub-menu** duplicate without first **li** to #sub-menu. Everything works fine just need to exclude first **li**

---

thanks to every1 ! all answers are good but one is very detail +1 to knowledge :)

Comment: Could you make a simple [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to work with?

Comment: What do you mean "move" ? Can it be  enough to remove first li? ( `$('.sub-menu >li:first-child').remove();` ). Btw your markup is invalid you are missing the `</li>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.sub-menu').clone().find('li + li').appendTo('#sub-menu');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Qmu2W/).

The above is a simple demo that doesn't remove the original, and assumes the element you're moving the `li` elements *to* is a list (either `ul` or `ol`).

The selector `li + li` finds all `li` elements which are the adjacent sibling of another `li` element; which excludes the `:first-child` by definition.

You could, of course, use the alternative sibling selector, the 'general-sibling' selector (the `~` character):

```
$('.sub-menu').clone().find('li:first-child ~ li').appendTo('#sub-menu');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Qmu2W/1/).

In terms of speed, the general-sibling approach seems to be quickest (in Chromium 27/Ubuntu 12.10), [JS Perf demo](http://jsperf.com/cloning-li-elements-other-than-the-first-child).

Having updated the previous JS Perf test, it seems, in fact, that using `filter()` is even faster:

```
$('.sub-menu').clone().find('li').filter(function(i) {
  return i > 0;
}).appendTo('#sub-menu');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Qmu2W/2/).

References:

- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: Awesome answer.  I didn't even know about the `+` and `~` selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sub-menu > li').filter(function(i, el){
    return i > 0;
}).appendTo('#sub-menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

Should do it

```
spec.find('ul.sub-menu > li:gt(0)').clone().prependTo("#sub-menu");
```

Sorry had a fiddle but Updated accidentally.